# Dockerize ruby script that takes directories as input/output

Tags: ruby, file-io, docker

I am very new to docker, and I need help to dockerize a ruby script that takes a a input directory and output directory.

i.e `generate_rr_pair.rb BuildRR -n /data/  -o /output`

What the script does, is it will take the -n option (input) and check if the directory exists, if it does it uses the files inside as input. The script will then output data to the -o option (output). If the output directory doesn't exist, the script will create the directory and output files there.

How can I create a Dockerfile to handle this? Should I pass these in, as environment variables? Or should I use mounted Volumes? But since the script handles fileIO, I am not sure if I want volumes. The input directory should already exist on the host, and the output directory will get created. Both directories, should remain after docker container stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [official ruby image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) in your docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild
CMD ["ruby", "generate_rr_pair.rb"]
```

Building the container as normal

```
docker build -t myruby .
```

Which can then be run as follows:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /data:/data -v /output:/output myruby BuildRR -n /data -o /output
```

Note that volume mappings are required if you want the ruby script within the container to operate on directories mounted on the host machine.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That is where I was getting confused, with the volume mappings.